# хотел сделать что бы при вводе команды бот отправлял в ЛС сообщение с правилами сервера, но не знаю как это сделать

Tags: discord.py, python-3.8

хотел сделать что бы при вводе команды бот отправлял правила сервера в ЛС и это выглядело так:

1. — Оскорбления
   └ Оскорбление — умышленное унижение чести и достоинства личности. Оскорбление кого либо на сервере запрещено.
2. — Рассылка спама.
   └ Реклама — распространение информации для привлечения внимания к объекту рекламирования. Использование рекламы разрешено только в канале #спам-и-реклама .

и т.д.

но не знаю как это сделать что бы файл c правилами был отдельно от основного кода
попробовал сделать так

```
@client.command()
async def rules(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send (open('RULES_SERVER.txt'))
```

но бот отправляет это

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='RULES_SERVER.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>

кто может помочь? буду очень благодарен

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше делать через саму команду или если хотите изменить, то делать через базу данных. А так я предлагаю неплохое решение.

```
@bot.command()
async def rules(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.description = (
        "1. — Оскорбления └ Оскорбление — умышленное унижение чести и достоинства личности. Оскорбление кого либо на сервере запрещено.\n"
        "2. — Рассылка спама. └ Реклама — распространение информации для привлечения внимания к объекту рекламирования. Использование рекламы разрешено только в канале #спам-и-реклама.\n"
    )
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: спасибо, это помогло, пока использую этот вариант, а затем как нибудь сделаю это через базу данных

Comment: Хорошо, пожалуйста, отметьте галочкой это решение